# How to read speed of waveform chart generated from labview?

Tags: labview

I need to know the speed of waveform chart of labview

[image: LabVIEW diagram screenshot]

the program generate 2 wave form shifted by 90 i need to make program to find the speed of both

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *the speed of waveform chart*. Are you trying to calculate a property of the signal itself (e.g. its period or frequency), or do you need to know something about the way the chart is displayed (its axis scale, etc)?

Comment: Yes bro i need to know the property of signal speed of it.

Comment: and you can see there are two signal i need to know which one is generated first.

Answer (score 2):

Neither waveform is "generated first". Every iteration of the loop will result in a different true/false value being placed onto the chart. On some iterations, the top one will update first; on other iterations, the bottom one will update first.

What you are seeing in the charts is NOT a coherent waveform. It is just a series of values that you have chosen to plot. There's no time data associated with this, just the values and an iteration count. The iteration counter is the clock of this algorithm, so, in that sense, both waveforms are generated at exactly the same rate at exactly the same time. (See below for comments about the Timed Loop.)

I doubt that this answers the question you think you are asking. You seem to want to know some information computed from these series of true/false values, but the terminology that you've used is not meaningful, and I cannot determine what information it is that you actually want.

I said earlier that the only clock for this algorithm is the iteration counter of the loop. You used a Timed Loop with a dt of 1. Are you on Windows? If so, then my statement is correct: The Timed Loop on Windows is only a simulation without any guarantee of timing, so you might as well be using a regular While Loop. If you are on a real-time OS with LabVIEW Real-Time module, then this is generating a point every 1 millisecond, so the speed of the iteration count is tied to the computer's clock, so the speed of both waveforms would be 1 millisecond.